# Error about hardware acceleration while loading AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I installed Android studio in my windows 7 OS and it doesn't allow me to load AVDs. It shows this error.

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! 
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I tried several things. I enabled "Intel Virtualization Technology" from the BIOS setup and re-installed XHAM installer from SDK Manager. But nothing changed. At last I tried to install "intelhaxm-android.exe" at the file location but it gives an error as below...!

```
"This computer meets the requirements for the XHAM, but intel
virtualization technology (VT-x) is not turned on. XHAM cannot be installed
untill VT-x is enabled. Please refer to the Intel XHAM documentation for the 
information"
```

But I have already enabled it from the BIOS!!

Comment: What anti-virus are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer can only use one type of VT at a time.  That's why many Windows 8 users are having trouble with Hyper-V.  Avast Antivirus (and probably others) also use this.  You can either uninstall your antivirus software, or search for the option that uses virtualization.  In Avast, you can do it as seen in the picture.  You have to reboot your computer after this change.[image]

Comment: I did it after you say. But it doesn't help!!

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Thanks. It was the problem. Now it works well. Problem solved. Thanks again for the great help.

Comment: Sweet, I'm glad. Please accept this answer if it worked.

Comment: In addition,  Avast hardware-assisted virtualization must be disabled only during the installation of the "intelhaxm-android.exe". After the installation I enabled it and rebooted, and it didn't affect the AVDs.

Answer (score 0):

To run the AVD with HAXM you require both the HAXM packages from the SDK manager along with installing https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager from intel.

Ensure that VT is enabled in your bios and then try again.  There is also a guide on the intel site that explains how to enable this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows